# How can i translate query to sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
select reservation_datetime
from LectureReservation
Inner Join Lecture
On LectureReservation.lecture_id = Lecture.id
Where Lecture.mentor_id = 1
```

This is my query and I want to change it to sequelize like

```
if (req.params.id) {
            LectureReservation
            .findAll({
                include: [{
                    model: Lecture,
                    where: { mentor_id: req.params.id },
                }],
                attributes: ['reservation_datetime'],
                where: {
                    lecture_id: Lecture.id,
                },
```

this.. I tried it so hard but can't find solution and my postman keep showing me

```
"name": "SequelizeEagerLoadingError"
```

this err..

plz help me to translate query to sequelize..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize will do _outer join without required = true.

The errors you have received usually is from association problem.

Try set logging :console.log and check the raw query.